# Jet.com API: How to get detailed list of products?

Tags: api, rest, jet.com-apis

I'm trying to create a custom API client for the Jet.com API.

My end-user use case is this: User should be able to display a detailed list of all products on their screen, including images, product name, etc etc

I'm already able to log in and programmatically list Product SKU url's using the `/api/merchant-skus` route; however, this does not give me any detailed information at all, only an array of relative URL's.

Is there a way to fetch the list of products with detailed information? Or do I have to hit the API once for each SKU?

Comment: Looks like it. You might want to contact the devs and ask for a detailed response format. In the mean time, you could request each separately and cache them.

Comment: That's what it looked like to me; I hope this isn't the case!

Comment: @monarch: Building your UI upon Jet Product API is not a good idea; Jet may anytime put a limit on API calls rate and amount to prevent API abuse of this kind. See my answer below as to why this is an abuse. And +1 for the hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Products API Documentation](https://developer.jet.com/docs/services/5565ca949a274a12b0b3a2a3/operations/5565d4be9a274a12b0b3a2ae) it seems that you'd need to request the data for each item.

You can do a parallel procedure (depending on your language) to get more than one request at once but According to my experience there's some undocumented limits on their side for how much requests you can do at once, so be carefull...

Comment: That's what it looked like to me. I will put in a feature request; sounds like a common requirement for someone using their API.

Answer (score 0):

[Jet.com Products API](https://developer.jet.com/docs/services/5565ca949a274a12b0b3a2a3/operations/5565d4be9a274a12b0b3a2ae) is RESTful Web API allowing Jet.com Partners to perform day to day maintenance of **their own** nomenclature (changes of price, inventory, shipping exceptions, etc.). Most `Products API` requests manipulate upon single individual Skus. The only other type of requests serve back a paginated list of Skus for verification purposes.

Jet.com `Products API` is **not** a tool for bulk nomenclature uploads/downloads. Bulk product uploads are supported today via [file uploads](https://developer.jet.com/data-flow-documentation). Bulk download of detailed product nomenclature feature is not considered essential for Jet.com Partners that already posess the bulk of own detailed product information. That's why it is not offered as of today.

Answer (score 0):

Currently jet has no any method defined which will show all products list but you can get detailed information per SKU once you posted it to Jet API using this call with "GET" method https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/merchant-skus/sku-id and response would be like this

```
`stdClass Object (
    [alternate_images] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_slot_id] => 1
                    [image_url] => http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/8JMAAOSwLVZVyWiu/s-l1600.jpg
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_slot_id] => 2
                    [image_url] => 
                )

        )

    [brand] => POWERSTEP
    [correlation_id] => map_9c22964b4dd549c49daac9b79759ae2d
    [main_image_url] => http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/dW0AAOSwu4BVyWia/s-l1600.jpg
    [merchant_id] => 0e79f9e041dd44d7967ab8ae82503368
    [merchant_sku] => POWERSTEP-PRO-PROTECH-Full-Length-ORTHOTIC-Mens-6-6-5
    [merchant_sku_id] => 55464dfbce6c45528ef18d4eea919a9e
    [mfr_part_number] => Does not apply
    [multipack_quantity] => 1
    [producer_id] => ironman
    [product_description] => Medical Grade Therapeutic Orthotics for heel and arch comfort that are Podiatry designed!  Accepted, approved, and recommended by the American Podiatric Medical Association (APMA). Powerstep Orthotics give your feet the support, comfort, and stability you need.   Unlike soft insoles, Powerstep orthotics are optimized to provide:

Powerstep Orthotics provide therapy for: Mild to moderate pronation Plantar Fasciitis Heel Spurs Neuromas Metatarsalgia

Product Features:  Proper foot posture and mechanics Injury prevention Pain Relief
    [product_title] => POWERSTEP PRO PROTECH Full Length ORTHOTIC Mens & Women's Size Mens 6-6.5/Womens 8-8.5
    [sku_last_update] => 2015-10-28T01:43:00.8114337+00:00
    [standard_product_codes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [standard_product_code] => 483029481041
                    [standard_product_code_type] => UPC
                )

        )

    [swatch_image_url] => http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/kDIAAOSwjVVVyWik/s-l1600.jpg
    [price] => 35.95
    [price_by_fulfillment_node] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [fulfillment_node_price] => 35.95
                    [fulfillment_node_id] => 18ce549c0e2542f9a8c23e4ed93a2180
                )

        )

    [inventory_by_fulfillment_node] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [fulfillment_node_id] => 18ce549c0e2542f9a8c23e4ed93a2180
                    [quantity] => 51
                )

        )

)`
```

I hope this will help you.